# How to disable partial update in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I know partial update in rails is good, but for my latest project, I need to disable it temporarily. Is there any way for me to do this in Rails 4?

I have tried to put `ActiveRecord::Base.partial_updates = false`  in my environment.rb like what being suggested [here](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/4/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-partial-updates), but it returns me a bunch of errors:

[image]

**UPDATE (ERROR MESSAGE)**

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `partia
iveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Users/ryzal_000/Sites/dotforge/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/Users/ryzal_000/Sites/dotforge/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Users/ryzal_000/Sites/dotforge/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Users/ryzal_000/Sites/dotforge/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you post the error message as plain text? That's a lot easier to work with than a tiny screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

From rails 4.1 `partial_updates` is removed you can check it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html